# Regular expression to find largest repeating pattern?

Tags: python, regex, string

How can I use regular expressions to find the largest repeating pattern?

For example, in the string "CATchickenchickenCATCATCATCATchickenchickenCATCATchicken"

I need a way to get this string: "CATCATCATCAT" since it is the largest repeating chunk of my substring "CAT"

How can I do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Users are encouraged to share their attempts

Comment: No regex is meant to find the longest substring. Extract all matches and check the longest with Python methods.

Comment: I dont think you can use regex for this. First of all we should know the pattern in order to match the string. If you are specifically looking for CAT then yeah we can use regex and find the matches for CAT and count its number of occurences. But if you want to generalize for any string then regex is not meant for it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

string = "CATchickenchickenCATCATCATCATchickenchickenCATCATchicken"

pattern = "((CAT)+)"

print(max(re.findall(pattern, string), key=lambda tpl: len(tpl[0]))[0])
```

Output:

```
CATCATCATCAT
>>>
```